# Detect grid nodes using OpenCV (or using something else)

Tags: python, opencv, pattern-recognition

I have a grid on pictures (they are from camera). After binarization they look like this (red is 255, blue is 0): 
[image: grid]

What is the best way to detect grid nodes (crosses) on these pictures?
Note: grid is distorted from cell to cell non-uniformly.

**Update:**

Some examples of different grids and thier distortions before binarization:
[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Have you tried detecting the lines using [hough transformation](http://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/dd/d1a/group__imgproc__feature.html#ga46b4e588934f6c8dfd509cc6e0e4545a&gsc.tab=0)? ([tutorial 1](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/imgproc/imgtrans/hough_lines/hough_lines.html), [tutorial 2](http://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/doc/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_houghlines/py_houghlines.html))

Comment: Yes, I've tried. But here is a distorted grid and hough works not good :(

Comment: Now l use harris corner detector, it works not bad, but it brings a lot of noisy points (wrong nodes) .

Comment: Can you post the non-binarized image?

Comment: Yes, I'll do it soon as I can! Approximately in 4 hours :>

Comment: @TobiasHermann Pictures have been added!

Comment: OK, these subjectively look more curved to me than the binarized version. Not an easy task, because they seem to come along in different colors, resolutions and styles (full lines, dotted). Even the distortion is not simply a perspective transform, since the paper is bent or kinked. Have you tried to follow the lines with [canny](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/imgproc/imgtrans/canny_detector/canny_detector.html)?

Comment: No, there is no binarizied image. I sent these pictures specially to specify distortion type: bend and wrinkled paper. And yes, line style can be different: full, dotted.

Comment: No, I didn't try canny but what profit can it be?

Comment: Perhaps canny could produce a better binarized edge image compared to the threshold-only approach.

Comment: I use clustering binarization by color and it works not bad relatively to adaptive gaussian thresholding. But binarization is not primary problem! The problem is how to detect grid nodes...

Comment: If I understand correctly, you currently use harris corner detector on the binarized image, which gives you suboptimal results. Perhaps the results were better with a better binarized image.

Comment: Ok. So, what should I do with canny results next? Apply harris corner detector to them?

Comment: I know nothing about this but what about [Histogram of Orientated Gradients](https://medium.com/@ageitgey/machine-learning-is-fun-part-4-modern-face-recognition-with-deep-learning-c3cffc121d78#.va7jia393) as used in that link?

Comment: @VermilionAzure looks very interesting, but not easy :) ! Thanks.

Comment: @Max Tkachenko: Yes, I would just try it. With the few examples you provided it is difficult to predict which approach will work for all your images.

Answer (score 2):

In cases like this I first try to find the best starting point.
So, first I thresholded your image (however I could also skeletonize it and just then threshold. But this way some data is lost irrecoverably):

[image: Imgur]

Then, I tried loads of tools to get the most prominent features emphasized in bulk. Finally, playing with Gimp's G'MIC plugin I found this:

[image: Imgur]

Based on the above I prepared a universal pattern that looks like this:

[image: Imgur]

Then I just got a part of this image:

[image: Imgur]

To help determine angle I made local Fourier freq graph - this way you can obtain your pattern local angle:

[image: Imgur]

Then you can make a simple thick that works fast on modern GPUs - get difference like this (missed case):

[image: Imgur]

When there is hit the difference is minimal; what I had in mind talking about local maximums refers more or less to how the resulting difference should be treated. It wouldn't be wise to weight outside of the pattern circle difference the same as inside due to scale factor sensitivity. Thus, inside with cross should be weighted more in used algorithm. Nevertheless differenced pattern with image looks like this:

[image: Imgur]

As you can see it's possible to differentiate between hit and miss. What is crucial is to set proper tolerance and use Fourier frequencies to obtain angle (with thresholded images Fourier usually follows overall orientation of image analyzed).
The above way can be later complemented by Harris detection, or Harris detection can be modified using above patterns to distinguish two to four closely placed corners.
Unfortunately, all techniques are scale dependent in such case and should be adjusted to it properly.
There are also other approaches to your problem, for instance by watershedding it first, then getting regions, then disregarding foreground, then simplifying curves, then checking if their corners form a consecutive equidistant pattern. But to my nose it would not produce correct results.

One more thing - libgmic is G'MIC library from where you can directly or through bindings use transformations shown above. Or get algorithms and rewrite them in your app.

Comment: Thank you for a such detailed answer. It's a good idea to use local Fourier. But what if pattern will be a cross with the other angle between cross lines? For example, not about 90 degree but 40?

Comment: This actually complicates matters. With small deviation from 90 degrees the problem can be mitigated with tolerance.

Comment: Missed the time to edit above - so continue here...
With bigger difference there are multiple approaches that can be applied. It all depends how deep you'd like to dig into this issue.

Actually the best, however pretty complicated, approach would be to apply Gabor filters with stepping angles, transform it into small line sections (adjusting appropriate tolerance before to limit noise) and then check intersections. 
While best, this approach would require some self learning algorithm and use of OCR optimization methods.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose that this can be a potential answer (actually mentioned in comments): http://opencv.itseez.com/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/feature_detection.html?highlight=hough#houghlinesp

There can also be other ways using skimage tools for feature detection.

But actually I think that instead of Hough transformation that could contribute to huge bloat and and lack of precision (straight lines), I would suggest trying Harris corner detection - http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/features2d/trackingmotion/harris_detector/harris_detector.html .

This can be further adjusted (cross corners, so local maximum should depend on crossy' distribution) to your specific issue. Then some curves approximation can be done based on points got.

Comment: Thank you! Can you talk more about this moment: "local maximum should depend on crossy' distribution"?

Comment: As you operate on bitmaps local maximums can be obtained by analyzing pixels together with their close surroundings. Like in FAST - see paper: http://lanl.arxiv.org/pdf/0810.2434 .

Your aim should be to find a rotation independent cross like distribution. This can be done both via calculation or iteratively. As GPU functions are now fast iterative approach would be sufficient. You must however take into consideration that region size should be adjusted to the scale of your pattern. Will try to produce an example in my next comment.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you cloud calculate  [Hough Lines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hough_transform) and determine the intersections. An OpenCV documentation can be found [here](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/imgproc/imgtrans/hough_lines/hough_lines.html)

Comment: Unfortunately, it brings a lot of  wrong noisy lines because grid is distorted :(

Comment: Ok, i see. So the [Harris corner detector](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/features2d/trackingmotion/harris_detector/harris_detector.html) won't help you either?

Comment: It has not helped :(